# Ubuntu 20.04 Router Issues

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, router

I had an old Ubuntu server that I was using as a router/firewall and home server. I recently pieced together a new one that was based on 20.04 and I copied the configuration over that I had been previously using (moving it to netplan from interfaces) but can't get it to work. The goal is to have it work as an internal router and dhcp server for my home network and be directly connected to the modem for routing external traffic. That said, it's not working. The external nic works exactly as expected and the dhcp configuration is assigning addresses correctly. However, the traffic isn't getting passed from the internal to external nic. I have a feeling it's something with the routing, but it's slightly beyond my knowledge. Any help would be appreciated. 
enp10s0 = external nic 
enp12s0 = internal nic

ip a

```
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
        inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 ::1/128 scope host
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    2: enp12s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 3c:8c:f8:ed:6f:b3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 192.168.1.1/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp12s0
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 fe80::3e8c:f8ff:feed:6fb3/64 scope link
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    3: enp10s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 70:85:c2:54:18:46 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 24.107.208.9/20 brd 24.107.223.255 scope global dynamic enp10s0
           valid_lft 3581sec preferred_lft 3581sec
        inet6 2600:6c40:700c:100:dd08:d359:b2cb:4825/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute
           valid_lft 600100sec preferred_lft 600100sec
        inet6 fe80::7285:c2ff:fe54:1846/64 scope link
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

dhcp.conf

```
    option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
    
    default-lease-time 4300;
    max-lease-time 7200;
    ddns-update-style none;
    authoritative;
    subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
         range 192.168.1.51 192.168.1.200;
         option routers 192.168.1.1;
         option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
         option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
    }
```

iptables (from iptables-save)

```
    *nat
    :PREROUTING ACCEPT [104:7022]
    :INPUT ACCEPT [40:3328]
    :OUTPUT ACCEPT [9:2250]
    :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [71:5639]
    -A POSTROUTING -o enp10s0 -j MASQUERADE
    COMMIT
    # Completed on Sat Oct  8 14:32:04 2022
    # Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sat Oct  8 14:32:04 2022
    *filter
    :INPUT ACCEPT [8:1326]
    :FORWARD ACCEPT [95:5648]
    :OUTPUT ACCEPT [144:16603]
    -A INPUT -i enp12s0 -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -i enp12s0 -o enp10s0 -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -i enp10s0 -o enp12so -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    COMMIT
```

netplan

```
   network:
      renderer: networkd
      ethernets:
         enp10s0:
            dhcp4:  true
            match:
               macaddress: 70:85:c2:54:18:46
            set-name: enp10s0
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 8.8.8.8
                - 8.8.4.4
         enp12s0:
            addresses:
            - 192.168.1.1/24
            dhcp4: false
            match:
               macaddress: 3c:8c:f8:ed:6f:b3
            set-name: enp12s0
            gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      version: 2
```

route -n

```
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
    0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp12s0
    0.0.0.0         24.107.208.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp10s0
    24.107.208.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 enp10s0
    24.107.208.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 enp10s0
    192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp12s0
```

Comment: For one `gateway4: 192.168.1.1` is wrong. You shouldn't have (extra) default route that uses the host itself as gateway. Just remove that line. Also, have you enable `ip_forward` in *sysctl*?

Comment: Btw your firewall rules (except the MASQUERADE one) are pointless because the chain policy of INPUT and FORWARD are ACCEPT and there are no fallback DROP / REJECT rules either.

Comment: @TomYan - Yes, I've enabled ip_forward. Forgot to include that in the initial post. I'll try removing the gateway line.
As for the firewall, I'm aware they aren't complete but wanted to include them to make sure I had everything there. I started with simple rules and left things open to try and get it working. I have complete firewall rules from my old setup that will eventually be in place once I get things figured out.